# how many command invocations with find -exec command {} +

Tags: find, gnu

find manpage states:

```
   -exec command {} +
          This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files,
          but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end;
          the total number of invocations of the  command  will  be
          much  less than the number of matched files.
```

Always thought that this would cause `find` to execute `command` exactly once.
Is there a way to know how many times command gets called?

Note this is important as if it's only one time as I've thought, then there's danger of building too large of a argument list for `command` to handle; but if find will end up splitting the invocations up (somewhat similar to `parallel`), then this would be mitigated.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable in a quantifiable way. The number of invocations is going to be inversely dependent on the length of each path argument.

Comment: The `+` is the extension that makes -exec run a list in a similar way to `xargs`. With a plain `{}`, the command does run once per filename. My Linux understands `getconf ARG_MAX` and tells me `2097152`. Your `command` could also be a script that chunks the initial arg-list and calls the final command multiple times with a more sensible arg-list, and could also handle Begin and End conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buffer used depends on the `find` version and seems to be about 256Kb in size in the SuSE box I've available here.

So to calculate how many times "command" gets invoked, you'd need to know the length of each found filepath, then it would be (approximately) the sum of all the path lengths increased by one for the dividing space, minus the command itself, divided by the buffer size.

E.g. you find 20,000 files with an average path length of 200 bytes, that is 4,020,000 bytes, divided by 256 Kb is 15.33, so you'd need about 16 calls.

The exact calculation would be slightly more complex to take into account the need of not breaking a filepath between two consecutive calls, but you get a ballpark figure.

See [here](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2014-June/081056.html) for a thread (with source code) where the size is reported to be 32Kb, and deemed unnecessarily low (now that I think of it, maybe my own `find` *is* using the syslimits. I haven't experimented); `coreutils`'s version, by inference, **appears to be four times that, i.e. 128 Kb**.

Answer (score 2):

The limit will depend on `find(1)`'s buffers, and what the command handles (kernel-dependent). Unless the very last percent of performance is critical, the defaults on your system should be fine.

If you are worrying about performance, consider the *whole* system that does this, and **measure** where the bottlenecks are. Chances are you'll be *very* surprised by your findings. Bentley, in his delicious "Writing efficient programs" (Prentice-Hall, 1982), sadly long out of print, shares several stories of careful "optimizations" that made essentially unused, fatally buggy code "faster" or optimized the idle loop of an operating system after measuring that it took up a substantial fraction of the computer's time. People are *notoriously* bad at guessing where inefficiencies lay. Besides, it pays off much more to work on the higher levels (system architecture, overall organization, algorithms and data structures) than on details.

Answer (score 2):

Preliminary note: the manual and your question uses `command` to denote the command, but since POSIX defines an utility literally named [`command`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html), my answer will use `cmmnd`.

---

If you want to actually run `cmmnd`(s) and just count the number of invocations (to know it *after* `find` finishes) then create a wrapper that does something you can count (e.g. prints to stderr, prints to a logfile, beeps) and eventually runs the `cmmnd`. Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "invoking cmmnd" >&2
cmmnd "$@"
```

Then use the `wrapper` instead of the `cmmnd` inside `find`.

Note `find` will use the `/absolute/path/to/wrapper` while creating commands that are not too long; then the wrapper will use `/absolute/path/to/cmmnd`. If the latter is longer then some command line(s) containing it may turn out to be too long anyway. So this approach is not as straightforward as we wish. You can extend the former path by supplying it to `find` verbatim with additional slashes (e.g. `/absolute/path/to/////wrapper`).

---

Now I assume you want to know the number *before* you decide to run `cmmnd`(s). Like in a case where calling the `cmmnd` twice is a bad thing (for whatever reason) and you want to make sure `find` will run it exactly once.

The above wrapper with `cmmnd "$@"` commented out can be used. Below are few other ideas (in the end not so different though).

Let's assume you want to do this:

```
find . -exec cmmnd … {} +
```

(where `…` denotes constant arguments). Find out what the absolute path to `cmmnd` really is. E.g. it can be `/bin/cmmnd`. Then run something like this:

```
find . -exec /aaa/zzzzz … {} +
```

where `/aaa/zzzzz` is a nonexistent command whose name is of the same length as `/bin/cmmnd`. Now `find` will build command lines with `/aaa/zzzzz` that will be of the same length as command lines with `/bin/cmmnd` would be. You will get

```
find: '/aaa/zzzzz': No such file or directory
```

one or more times. Count them to get the number you want. This simple approach:

```
find . -exec /aaa/zzzzz … {} + 2>&1 | wc -l
```

is not the best because `find` may *also* print e.g. `permission denied` for some files it encounters. But if you create `/aaa/zzzzz` as a valid executable that prints exactly one line (it can be an empty line), then this should work:

```
find . -exec /aaa/zzzzz … {} + | wc -l
```

Another improvement is to name the tool `/a` (instead of `/aaa/zzzzz`), and call it as `/////a` or `/////////////////a` etc., depending on the length you need. Example:

```
find . -exec /////////a … {} + | wc -l
```

For completeness, this is what `a` may look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
```

It's almost like our wrapper without `cmmnd "$@"`, it uses the stdout though.

Notes:

- The exact number of `/` characters is not critical. A mistake by few will not change the result *drastically*. If you need an *estimate* result, you can blindly use `///////////a` or so, unless the path to the `cmmnd` is unusually long. Note that using exactly `/a` will give you the lower bound.
- In practice you often have other tests before `-exec cmmnd … {} +`. If you replace `cmmnd` with `/////////a` or so, the other tests will still be performed. You should not omit them because they decide what pathnames get to `-exec` in the first place. But if the tests do or change something, it may be that performing them without the `cmmnd` is wrong.

  E.g. you may want to delete files with `-delete -exec cmmnd … {} +`, where `cmmnd` generates a report on files that have been deleted. In this case using `/////////a` will delete files *without* generating any report. So think before you act.
- Make sure tests/actions/whatever other than `-exec /////////a … {} +` print nothing to stdout. Or let `/a` use some other channel.
- Processing the given directory tree(s) and performing (other) tests may take a while even without `cmmnd`(s).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the standard text says:

> The size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that execution of the utility does not cause the system's {ARG_MAX} limit to be exceeded.

So it shouldn't build an argument list too large to execute. That would defeat the point of a feature like this.

How many invocations it does exactly, is up to the implementation, and is probably something you shouldn't care too much about. The standard does promise that invocations of the same `-exec` clause don't overlap, which may be relevant for correctness if you execute something that has outside state.

However, on Linux, the actual maximum size of the command line arguments is based on the stack size, and can be indirectly changed with `ulimit -s`. And it appears that unlike e.g. `xargs`, the `find` on my Debian and Ubuntu doesn't actually check the limit at runtime, so it's theoretically possible to hit problems.

```
$ mkdir bar
$ touch bar/{00000..99999}
$ ulimit -Ss 512
$ getconf ARG_MAX
131072
$ find bar -type f -exec sh ./args.sh {} +
find: ‘sh’: Argument list too long
find: ‘sh’: Argument list too long
...
```

However, the default for `ulimit -s` is 8192, so you're not likely to get that problem, except on a very constrained system.